# Keras R Custom Metric - Average y_true of subset based upon y_pred

Tags: r, keras, metrics

I am trying to create a custom metric in keras.  I want to know the average y_truth of the top  1% of the y_pred.  I'm willing to settle for either a fixed number of observations like below or  a the average of y_truth which y_predict is greater than a hardcode, but top 1% would be best.

I've tried the following...

```
Metric_Top_Rets <- custom_metric("Top_Rets", function(y_true,y_pred) {
k_mean(k_in_top_k(y_pred,y_true,1000))
})


model1 %>% compile(
  loss = "mse",
  optimizer =  optimizer_adam(.0001),
  metrics = list(Metric_Top_Rets)
)
```

The model will compile, but will not fit.

I can output the just the average y_true, but can't get any subset of the y_true based upon y_pred.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This R package is helpful for making reproducible code examples for venues like SO: https://reprex.tidyverse.org/